# How do I make this property nullable?

Tags: c#, entity

I have this line in C#, where incoming.icon is a property of a custom model, and dataItem.Icon is the property of a custom entity.

```
dataItem.Icon = incoming.icon;
```

The compiler complains because incoming.icon is nullable but dataItem.Icon isn't. Here is the dataItem 'Icon' property definition in the entity:

```
    public Guid Icon {
        get {
            return  ValidationHelper.GetGuid(GetValue("Icon"), Guid.Empty);
        }
        set {
            SetValue("Icon", value);
        }
    }
```

How do I make this property nullable in order to fix the error?

Answer (score 4):

Like this:

```
public Guid? Icon 
{
    get 
    {
        return (Guid?)ValidationHelper.GetGuid(GetValue("Icon"), Guid.Empty);
    }
    set 
    {
        SetValue("Icon", value.GetValueOrDefault());
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Nullable is the struct that you're looking for.

```
public Nullable<Guid> Icon
```

This can be written in shorthand like so:

```
public Guid? Icon
```

If your design is that you don't want `null` values being set on dataItem.icon, then you might want to check incoming.icon and only get it's value if it exists instead.  Like this:

```
if (incoming.icon.HasValue)
    dataItem.Icon = incoming.icon.Value;
```